cant build dioxus project when i use tokio dependence
when i run a dioxus project and add tokio in dependence
tokio = { version = "1.37.0", features = ["full"] }

it will show
error[E0599]: no method named `deregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::UdpSocket>` in the current scope
   --> /Users/xy/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/mio-0.8.11/src/net/udp.rs:635:20
    |
635 |         self.inner.deregister(registry)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<UdpSocket>`
    |
   ::: /Users/xy/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/mio-0.8.11/src/io_source.rs:62:1
    |
62  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `deregister` not found for this struct


 Some errors have detailed explanations: E0412, E0425, E0432, E0433, E0599.
 For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
 error: could not compile `mio` (lib) due to 44 previous errors

i tried cargo clean and cargo update but it did not work

Which template are you using?

This is related to Dioxus #1330, to summarize tokio does not play nicely with WebAssembly. Their incompatability is also discussed here and according to Tokio #1597 they have no plans to make tokio work with WASM.
